# MATLAB: Failed to correctly write using csvwrite()

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write three different arrays into 3 columns in a csv file. This what I have tried :

```
str = 'This is the matrix: ' ;

a= [1 2 3 4 5 6 ]'; 
csvwrite('C:\Users\ganesh\Desktop\data.csv', a);

b= [11 12 13 14 15 16]';

csvwrite('C:\Users\ganesh\Desktop\data.csv', b, 1, 0);

c= [21 22 23 24 25 26]';

csvwrite('C:\Users\ganesh\Desktop\data.csv', c, 2, 0);
```

But it does not work. Only last data is coming that too in a row. I have tried to put offset for columns. 
Did I made a mistake somewhere ?   ALso is there a way I can write these data in a single function call , rather than calling three time as shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your data in a matrix:

```
 m = [1 2 3 4 5 6
      11 12 13 14 15 16
      21 22 23 24 25 26];
 csvwrite('data.csv', m);
```